# Conway Game of Life

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I am trying to write Conway's game of life. Right now I am representing the living cells with plus signs and the dead ones with negative signs. My first generation will appear fine then I get an out of bounds error. Also I would like to add the generation counter for the user as they are being printed. here is the error code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
at Life.Neighbors(Life.java:56)
at Life.nextGen(Life.java:35)
at Life.main(Life.java:18)
```

Here is the code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Life {

    public static boolean[][] gen(){
        boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[10][10];
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)
                if( Math.random() > 0.7 )
                    matrix[i][j] = true;
        return matrix;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean[][] world = gen();
        show(world);
        System.out.println();
        world = nextGen(world);
        show(world);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(s.nextLine().length() == 0){
            System.out.println();
            world = nextGen(world);
            show(world);

        }
    }

    public static boolean[][] nextGen(boolean[][] world){
        boolean[][] newWorld 
            = new boolean[world.length][world[0].length];
        int num;
        for(int i = 0; i < world.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < world[0].length; j++){
                num = Neighbors(world, i, j);
                if( occupiedNext(num, world[i][j]) )
                    newWorld[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
        return newWorld;
    }

    public static boolean occupiedNext(int Neighbors, boolean occupied){
        if( occupied && (Neighbors == 2 || Neighbors == 3))
            return true;
        else if (!occupied && Neighbors == 3)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static int Neighbors(boolean[][] world, int row, int col) {
        int num = world[row][col] ? -1 : 0;
        for(int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++)
            for(int j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; j++)
                if( inbounds(world, i, j) && world[i][j] )
                    num++;

        return num;
    }

    public static boolean inbounds(boolean[][] world, int i, int j) {
        return i >= 0 && i < world.length && j >= 0 &&
        i < world[0].length;
    }
    public static void show(boolean[][] matrix){
        String s = "";
        for(boolean[] row : matrix){
            for(boolean val : row)
                if(val)
                    s += "+";
                else
                    s += "-";
            s += "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(s);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the specific section of code that you're having trouble with. Where are you seeing the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception? What have you tried on your own, to figure out what the problem is? Also, as far as your second question is concerned, what solutions have you tried?

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (An then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: *Where* do you get the exception? You want us to just guess, or create a project and run it, or...?

Comment: Also, this is a typical homework assignment. Have you tried a debugger as others suggested. SO is not just a default place for when you get stuck on homework...you should try this on your own a little first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inbounds` method that you are using to make sure the coordinates (i,j) are not out of bounds is wrong:

```
public static boolean inbounds(boolean[][] world, int i, int j) {
    return i >= 0 && i < world.length && j >= 0 && i < world[0].length;
}
```

Indeed, in the last check, you are comparing `i` with the `world[0].length`, when it should be `j`:

```
public static boolean inbounds(boolean[][] world, int i, int j) {
    return i >= 0 && i < world.length && j >= 0 && j < world[0].length;
}
```

Comment: Yes that solved the error I had been trying to find it. I figured it was one of the variables just couldnt seem to find which one

Answer (score 2):

A quick observation, you wrote:

```
public static boolean inbounds(boolean[][] world, int i, int j) {
        return i >= 0 && i < world.length && j >= 0 &&
        i < world[0].length;
```

I think perhaps that final comparison should be:

```
... && j < world[0].length;
```

instead of i.